# Document Map in Visual Studio Data Tools for SSRS report - back option

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools

I have a question on how to use Document Map for for a SSRS report. I'm able to get the map using a group called Name which is what I want, but I also want the ability to go back to the main page of the report using back in the document map or by clicking somewhere in the page that the user is on. The tricky part is that it has to work when exported to PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding a parent group to your report.

Select the highest level group in your report and then add a parent group.
You can group by any value so just type 1 in the group by expression and this will be OK.
Then right-click the group and set the document map value to something like `="Top"` or whatever you want to show in the map.

You can hide the column that is created if required.

"Top" will now appear at the top of the map and users will be able to use this when rendered to PDF if bookmarks are showing.